# Como atrelar uma variavel de titulo em uma função de plotagem de grafico?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

CODIGO:

```
def cria_grafico (x,y,titulo):

  plt.figure(figsize = (10,8))

  sns.boxplot(x=x,y = y, data=dados,order=renda_ordenada)

  plt.title()
```

Na parte `plt.title()` como devo informar a variável título?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Para criar um título usando a variável da sua função, apenas adicione a variável dentro do campo,  o seu caso `titulo`:

```
plt.title(titulo)
```

Veja aqui na documentação do `matplotlib`

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/titles_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-titles-demo-py